# How to add second OpenAPI document to swagger UI when using [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "CustomApiGroup")]

Tags: asp.net, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, openapi, swashbuckle

**How do I add second definition to swagger UI in ASP.NET Core?**

I unterstand that using `GroupName` property of `ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute` I can create separate OpenApi document:

```cs
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "ABCv1")]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public AbcController
{
     [HttpGet("records")]
     public IActionResult GetRecords()....
}
```

The Open API document is now accessible via URL: `/swagger/ABC_v1/swagger.json`

However, I don't see the document in swagger UI at `/swagger/index.html` in the definitions dropdown:

[image: swagger ui screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal example:

program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(op =>
{
    op.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "My API",
        Version = "v1"
    });

    op.SwaggerDoc("ABCv1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "My API",
        Version = "ABCv1"
    });
    //op.DocInclusionPredicate((name, api) => true);
});
```

.....

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/ABCv1/swagger.json", "ABCv1");

        
    });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v1")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
.......
}



[HttpGet]
        [Route("sign")]
        [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "ABCv1")]
        
        public async Task<IActionResult> SignDocument(....)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I used this predicate to set "default" swagger document: `c.DocInclusionPredicate((name, api) => name == (api.GroupName ?? "v1");`. It adds api's without GroupName to "v1"